# Android, how can i use callback from hellper method in controller?

Tags: java, android, interface

I have the following calling of the Helper method in the controller:

```
DialogHelper.showListDialog(R.string.select_recipient_please, recipientsArr, null, context);
```

And helper method:

```
public static void showListDialog(int title, String[] items, Drawable icon, Context ctx) {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctx)
                .title(title)
                .items(items)
                .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                        Logger.d("Selected");
                        Logger.d(String.valueOf(which));
                        /**
                         * If you use alwaysCallSingleChoiceCallback(), which is discussed below,
                         * returning false here won't allow the newly selected radio button to actually be selected.
                         **/
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .positiveText("Select")
                .show();
    }
```

And i would like to process overridden **onSelection** method in the Controller instead of the helper.

How can i do it in the right way please? Should I Use interface for this?

Many thanks for any advice or example.

**EDIT: ADDED EXAMPLE WHICH IS NOT WORKING FOR ME**

Controller method:

```
public void showRecipientsPicker(ArrayList<String> recipents){
        try {
            String[] recipientsArr = new String[recipents.size()];
            recipientsArr = recipents.toArray(recipientsArr);
            DialogHelper dh = new DialogHelper(context);

            dh.showListDialog(R.string.select_recipient_please, recipientsArr, null, new DialogHelperListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                    Logger.d("TEST");
                    Logger.d(String.valueOf(which));
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e){
            Logger.d(e.getMessage());
            toastHelper.showToast(R.string.cannot_show_recipients,
                    Constants.Global.TOAST_DURATION_MEDIUM);
            TrackingEventLogHelper.logException(e, Constants.Global.EXCEPTION,
                    Constants.ExceptionMessage.EXC_CANNOT_SHOW_RECIPIENT_LIST, true);

        }
    }
```

Interface class:

```
public interface DialogHelperListener  {
    void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text);
}
```

Helper class:

```
public class DialogHelper {

    private Context mCtx;

    public DialogHelper(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }


    /**
     * Creating a list dialog only requires passing in an array of strings
     */
    public void showListDialog(int title, String[] items, Drawable icon, DialogHelperListener callback) {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this.mCtx)
                .title(title)
                .items(items)
                .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, (MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice) callback)
                .positiveText("Select")
                .show();
    }





}
```

**It is throwing the following exception:**

```
controller.MessageController$2 cannot be cast to com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$ListCallbackSingleChoice
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the callback interface as an argument to the function, so something like this:

```
public static void showListDialog(int title, String[] items, Drawable icon, Context ctx, MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice callback) {
  new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctx)
                .title(title)
                .items(items)
                .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, callback)
                .positiveText("Select")
                .show();
}
```

Then in your controller, you can implement this behaviour:

```
showListDialog(title, items, icon, ctx, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice(){
  @Override
  public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
    //Do something here
  }
})
```

**EDIT**

The thing going wrong here is that your method accepts a `DialogHelperListener` and you try to cast it to `MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice`. Now I am going to assume that you want to use the `DialogHelperListener` interface for your controller code. You cannot simply cast that, you would need to implement the `MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice` and call your own interface, like this:

```
public void showListDialog(int title, String[] items, Drawable icon, DialogHelperListener callback) {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this.mCtx)
                .title(title)
                .items(items)
                .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice(){
                  @Override
                  public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                    callback.onSelection(dialog, view, which);
                  }
                })
                .positiveText("Select")
                .show();
}
```

Though I am not sure why you would want to use an interface that directly mimics the `MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice` interface

Comment: I would like to call it via the stand alone listener(interface), how to do it please?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with that, could you describe exactly what you want?

Comment: You are right, stand-alone listener for this does not make the sense.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i do it in the right way please? Should I Use interface for
>   this?

Yes, I guess you will need to use Interface and receive callbacks based on your events.